# webview javascript interface function not found

Tags: javascript, android, android-webview

I am trying to pass json data from a java to my web view
this is my code:

interface:

```
public class ChartsJavaScriptInterface {
public ChartsJavaScriptInterface() {

}

    public String getData(){
        String s = "[ {date: 'A', frequency: .00100, date: '1-May-11', close: 1}," +
                    "{date: 'B', frequency: .01492, date: '2-May-14', close: 2}," +
                    "{date: 'C', frequency: .02782, date: '3-May-14', close: 3}," +
                    "{date: 'D', frequency: .04253, date: '4-May-15', close: 5}," +
                    "{date: 'D', frequency: .04253, date: '5-May-15', close: 4}," +
                    "{date: 'D', frequency: .04253, date: '7-May-15', close: 2},]";


        return s;
    }

}
```

activity:

```
    chartsView = (WebView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.charts_chart_view);

    chartsView.addJavascriptInterface(new ChartsJavaScriptInterface(), "chartInterface");
    chartsView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient());
    chartsView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    chartsView.setInitialScale(30);
    chartsView.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
    chartsView.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
    chartsView.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);
    chartsView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/line.html");
```

html file:

```
....
draw(JSON.parse(chartInterface.getData()));
....
```

logCat:
08-25 13:34:57.397: E/Web Console(19809): Uncaught TypeError: 
Object [object Object] has no method 'getData' at file:///android_asset/line.html:345

what's my mistake? 
help please?

Thanks,
Ilan

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you forgot to add the `JavascriptInterface` annotation:

```
@JavascriptInterface
public String getData(){
    String s = "[ {date: 'A', frequency: .00100, date: '1-May-11', close: 1}," +
                "{date: 'B', frequency: .01492, date: '2-May-14', close: 2}," +
                "{date: 'C', frequency: .02782, date: '3-May-14', close: 3}," +
                "{date: 'D', frequency: .04253, date: '4-May-15', close: 5}," +
                "{date: 'D', frequency: .04253, date: '5-May-15', close: 4}," +
                "{date: 'D', frequency: .04253, date: '7-May-15', close: 2},]";
    return s;
}
```

Please take a look [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/webapps/webview.html) for a reference how to build a bridge between `JS` and `Android`

Comment: thanks, but know i get Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token d at file:///android_asset/line.html:1.     and when i add the json hard coded as a var data =[...] it works. this error only happens when i use the interface

Comment: @ilan it's not the problem of Android now, it is a problem of JSON. You can start from checking is it valid or not. If you check in debugger you will find, that at least you are getting result from `getData`, it means interface is working fine.